# Файл 404 для статичного сайта

Tags: .htaccess

Есть запись в .htaccess - `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

Вопрос вот в чем. Файл 404 работает хорошо, но только если он вызван с главной страницы сайта. С дочерних страниц, которые вложены в другие папки он вызывается, но без привязки стилей. Как сделать так, чтобы стили оставались на месте ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте в файле 404.html либо абсолютные ссылки на все файлы стилей, либо относительные, но с самого корня сайта (ссылка должна начинаться со слеша). Ну и проверьте, что в файлах стилей тоже стоят относительные пути от корня сайта, если используются локальные шрифты или картинки).

Comment: Точно, благодарю..совсем вылетело из головы )